# socket.io 2.0.3 get a list of all connected client ids

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a socket.io `v2.0.3` server with namespaces.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(88);

io.of('/namespace').on('connection', function(client){

      client.on('checkForOffline', function(event){

          for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++){
              console.log(client[event[i]["id"]].connected);
              //doesn't work
          } 
      });

});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'connected' of undefined

I know about using `on('disconnect')` but then I won't be able to determine whether a *user* is browsing around client area or actually closed the window/disconnected.

Thanks, help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
var connectedClients = Object.keys(io.of('/namespace').clients().connected);
```

Loads an array of all connected client ids.

To check if a client id is connected, loop through the `connectedClients[n]` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `client` variable is not an array.
That is why you: `Cannot read property 'connected'`.

`client` variable saved only information about **once** client.
I have a question... What is in the `event` variable?

Comment: `event` contains a list of connected clients from the `on('connect')` event

Comment: `io.of('/namespace').clients().connected` is an object and contains all connected client ids and more data, however I can't seem to access that object for a specific id..

Comment: @gitterio, This will work before version 1.0, if I'am not wrong.

Comment: There's answers in other questions for versions `< 2.0.3` though they don't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
io.clients((error, clients) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(clients); // => [6em3d4TJP8Et9EMNAAAA, G5p55dHhGgUnLUctAAAB]
});
```

Source
https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-clients-callback